# How to define a new class method in R?

Tags: r

Defining a new function is straight forward - e.g. `myfunct <- function(x) { x * 2}`

How can we define a new **class method** in R, such that `obj$newmethod` calls method `newmethod` on the object `obj`?

#### Desired output

How can we define a method on `obj` so that it can be called like so

```
obj <- 3
obj$newmethod
[1] 6
```

#### What I tried so far

```
newmethod <- function(x) { 
  x * 2
}

obj$newmethod

# Error in obj$newmethod : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

#### Examples of existing class methods

[RSelenium package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/RSelenium.pdf#page=9) uses a lot of class methods, for example `remDr$closeServer()` calls the method `closeServer()` on the object `remDr` (which is of class `remoteDriver`) - there are many more examples under the [Fields](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/RSelenium.pdf#page=9) section of the manual (pages 9 - 13).

Comment: ? what's the end goal

Comment: @JorgeLopez very fair question. TBH, I just want to learn about the class method construct, as I use it regularly (in RSelenium), but I do not understand it. I have been reading some of [Hadley's documentation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html) but (so far) have not found explicit reference to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) Reference Classes**  RSelenium uses Reference Classes which is an OO system that is included with R. Rselenium defines 3 reference classes: `errorHandler`, `remoteDriver` and `webElement`.

In terms of the example in the question we can use the code below.  No packages are used in the code here.

For more information on reference classes see `?ReferenceClasses`.

```
# define class, properties/fields and methods
Obj <- setRefClass("Obj", 
  fields = list(obj = "numeric"),
  methods = list(
    newmethod = function() 2 * obj
  )
)

# instantiate an object of class Obj
obj1 <- Obj$new(obj = 3)

# run newmethod
obj1$newmethod()
## [1] 6
```

**2) proto**  The example code in the question suggests that you may be looking for an object based (rather than class based) system.  In that case  the proto package provides one and your example works with a slight change in syntax.

```
library(proto)

p <- proto(obj = 0, newmethod = function(.) 2 * .$obj)
p$obj <- 3
p$newmethod()
## [1] 6
```

**3) local** If you don't need inheritance and other features of object orientation you could just do this. No packages are used.

```
Obj <- local({
  obj <- 0
  newmethod <- function() 2 * obj
  environment()
})

Obj$obj <- 3
Obj$newmethod()
## [1] 6
```

**4) S3**  S3 is included with R and is the most widely used OO system in R; however, it is different than conventional OO systems being based on the ideas of the dylan language so it may not correspond exactly to what you are looking for.

```
# constructor 
obj <- function(x) structure(x, class = "obj")

# method
newmethod <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("newmethod")
newmethod.obj <- function(x, ...) 2 * x

# create object obj3 of class "obj" and apply newmethod to it.
obj3 <- obj(3)
newmethod(obj3)
## [1] 6
```

**5) Other** Other OO systems are S4 (included in R), the R6 package and the R.oo package.  Also try `demo("scoping")` for another approach.

Answer (score 1):

For simple cases, you could do

```
f = function(x, newmethod = 2 * x) {
    list(x = x, newmethod = newmethod)
}

obj = f(3)

obj$newmethod
```

Comment: Thanks so much. The code runs but what is it doing? And are we cheating here by defining `obj = f(3)` rather than simply `obj = 3` ? Sorry for the confused questions

Comment: he created a function that depends on parameter x. And he creates a list object with two elements (element x, and element newMethod). So, by applying f(3) he creates a list object where the first element is equal to 3 and the second one is equal to 6 (the name of the first element is x, and the name of the second element is newmethod)